# How to call the following apex class from apex trigger. the trigger needs to work on after update

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, record

```
    public class StatusClosedHandler { 
     public static void statuschange(String RecordId){ 
        integer count = 0;              
        List<Service_Request__c> srequest = new List<Service_Request__c>();
        for(Service_Line__c sl : [Select id, Name, Status__c,Line_Type__c, Service_Request__r.Status__c,Service_Request__r.Name from Service_Line__c WHERE Service_Request__c = :RecordId ]){
        if(sl.Status__c == 'Completed'){ 
        count++;
} 
        if(count == 3){
        Service_Request__c sr = new Service_Request__c();
        sr.id = sl.Service_Request__c;
        sr.status__c = 'Closed';
        srequest.add(sr);
 } 
 }
        update srequest; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular limit you're running into when calling it?

Comment: if we pass just one record at a time then limit is not being exceeded

Comment: but a trigger can act on multiple records, like the answer below says it needs to be bulkified, you'll likely hit a soql limit at some point the way it's written

Comment: i am actually new to salesforce, could you suggest the best possible way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't. This class is not suitable for use in a trigger context because it runs a query and a DML operation for each record Id.

This code needs to be rewritten in accordance with principles of [bulkification](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) to be used in a trigger context. There are a variety of helpful trigger handler frameworks available that provide skeletons for building handler classes that a trigger can call with a collection of records to operate upon; I recommend you adopt one of them.